# Writing excel formula for HYPERLINK using jxl(java) fails

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, jxl

I'm trying to write a HYPERLINK into excel using jxl in java, but the write fails as below. Please suggest what can be done

```
String scn = "=HYPERLINK(\"D:\\snaps\\"+step_num+".jpg\",\"Click\")";
Formula link = new Formula(3,0,scn);
wws.addCell(link);


java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Unknown Source)
    at jxl.biff.formula.BinaryOperator.getOperands(BinaryOperator.java:61)
    at jxl.biff.formula.StringFormulaParser.parseCurrent(StringFormulaParser.java:240)
    at jxl.biff.formula.StringFormulaParser.parse(StringFormulaParser.java:113)
    at jxl.biff.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:129)
    at jxl.write.biff.FormulaRecord.initialize(FormulaRecord.java:160)
    at jxl.write.biff.FormulaRecord.setCellDetails(FormulaRecord.java:243)
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.addCell(WritableSheetImpl.java:1155)
    at framework.WrapperMethods.writeExcel(WrapperMethods.java:174)
    at framework.WrapperMethods.setValueById(WrapperMethods.java:80)
    at sample.T24Login.main(T24Login.java:55)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change by removing `=`

From

```
String scn = "=HYPERLINK(\"D:\\snaps\\"+step_num+".jpg\",\"Click\")";
```

to

```
String scn = "HYPERLINK(\"D:\\snaps\\"+step_num+".jpg\",\"Click\")";
```

Comment: In the Excel the formula cell is displyed as normal text, click on that though retrieves the desired screen shot. How to make the Formula link cell to be displayed like hyperlink ?